# selecting triple unique(or distinct) value from mysql

Tags: mysql, distinct

The database looks like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc89c

Column translations to understand it better:
`pardavejas` - seller, 
`kaina` - price, 
`data` - date

I need to get the latest prices of each model_id and pardavejas group.

The query "should" look like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `pardavejas`, DISTINCT `model_id`... order by date and have only the latest date
```

Thanks for all the help.

P.S. Basically I'm making price history for each model and seller. I need to get the latest prices without any older dates.

Comment: So you are trying to get the latest date for each pair of pardavejas and model_id?

Comment: do you need to show all the unique tuples?

Comment: @Barranka I need to get the latest dates and prices of each model_id and pardavejas group

Comment: @TrueSkillZ Why on earth do you store the dates as `varchar`? (at least in your SQL fiddle example). Change the data type to `date`

Comment: Never used MAX in mysql, so I always had dates as varchar, changed it to date and everything is working. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the sounds of it, this would work:

```
SELECT MAX(date), pardavejas, model_id
FROM kainosn
GROUP BY pardavejas, model_id
```

That will give you the largest date for each unique (pardavejas, model_id)

Comment: Apparently MAX(data) doesn't work with the date format.. The query returns that the max date it 2013-9-9 , but the actual max date would be 2013-9-26

Comment: What kind of column contains the date value?

Comment: It didn't return the correct date because I was using varchar, not date. This is the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

The `distinct` keyword deduplicates rows, and you only need to write it once:

```
select distinct `pardavejas`, `model_id`, `date`
from `kainosn`
```

This will return all the unique rows.

But, if you want the max date, `group by` is the way to go:

```
select pardavejas, model_id, max(`date`) as maxDate
from kainosn
group by pardavejas, model_id
```

This will give you the max date for every unique combination of `pardavejas` and `model_id`.

Comment: Same problem as the answer above. MAX date returns 2013-09-09, not the actual 2013-9-26 max date

Comment: @TrueSkillZ For which (`pardavejas`,`model_id`) is `2013-09-26` the maximum date?

Comment: from http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b8c4/3 : (1099, 10, 13, 1985, '2013-9-26', '1380214130')

Comment: @TrueSkillZ I've checked your SQL Fiddle example, and you are making a **very big** mistake: you are storing dates as `varchar`. **Change the data type for the column and try again**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b8c4/1

Comment: That's true, I never used date type because I just needed the date as text. The problem is solved by changing the type to date.

Comment: @TrueSkillZ Data types are there for a reason. You should be careful when designing your database, and use the appropriate types for every column. That will save you a lot of trouble and a lot of time.